# What is "Test Execution Wall Clock"?

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, manual-testing

Can anyone help me out with an answer for: What is "test execution wall clock"?

I have this information from a job description:

> These are the few questions which QA or Lead QA has to answer. Need
>   write-up / answers on the below from both:
>
> 1. Define “test execution wall clock.”
> 2. How many test programs have you written in C/C++/JAVA/PERL or
>      PYTHON over the past year?
> 3. For the test cases you’ve written, what is the wall clock? How
>      frequently did the test cases run?

Comment: who was asking this? What is the context?

Comment: @PhilKirkham Kirkham  Even I was surprised when I saw this in one of the Job requirements which came up to me today for one of the biggest organizations.

Comment: can you share a link? or more of the posting so we can see the context?

Comment: @PhilKirkham I do not have link but I have these questions :
These are the few questions which QA or Lead QA has to answer.
Need write-up / answers on the below from both:
1) Define “test execution wall clock.”
2) How many test programs have you written in C/C++/JAVA/PERL or PYTHON over the past year?
3) For the test cases you’ve written, what is the wall clock? How frequently did the test cases run?

Answer (score 1):

Test execution wall clock is simply a way of referring to the amount of time test execution takes/took. They key point point of using the term being to ensure there's no ambiguity that they want the total time (including time that the CPU is not active, e.g. waiting time built into your tests) included in the time taken to execute.

In the case of the sample question you gave: 3) For the test cases you’ve written, what is the wall clock? How frequently did the test cases run?

What they're trying to figure out here seems to be, how quickly have your tests executed in the past? The frequency part of the question indicates that what they're interested in here (or probably trying to achieve) is a suite of automated tests that are executed with builds and run quickly - their goal is probably highly effective and fast continuous integration with automated testing built in.

(Although perhaps it could also be read as how long it took you to write the tests rather than execute them)

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649399/how-to-profile-wall-clock-time-of-tests-running-in-maven-surefire) help? Was one of the first search results, I don't know what that "wall clock" is but I hope it can help....

Comment: I got one of the requirement for QA/ QA Lead through of the Esteemed Organization. May be it would help me to answer for one of the Job Requirement which I got today.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if wall clock refers to actual real-time spent on a task versus person hours. For example, if 5 testers worked on a test execution for 5 hours the wall clock would be 5 hours while the person time would be 25 hours.

It could also be referring to how long in actual time an automated test takes to run versus CPU time in multi-threaded applications.

Answer (score 0):

I guess [this wikipedia post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) should explain the definition of "Wall clock". See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time

I hope you can now apply it to the "test execution" part.